# How to create date regex with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, regex, rx-swift

I am trying to make a regex string for date like [this](https://www.regextester.com/97612). My code (Swift 5 example):

```
let dateValidator = TextValidator(input: dateTextField.rx.text.asObservable(), regex: try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:
    #"^\s*(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])\.(1[012]|0?[1-9])\.((?:19|20)\d{2})\s*$"#))

let v = Observable.combineLatest(dateValidator.validate(), anotherValidator.validate()) {
    (date, another) in
    return date && another
}
//another code

class TextValidator {
    var input: Observable<String?>
    var regex: NSRegularExpression

    init(input: Observable<String?>, regex: NSRegularExpression) {
        self.input = input
        self.regex = regex
    }

    func validate() -> Observable<Bool> {
        return input.map { text in
            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: text!.utf8.count)
            return self.regex.firstMatch(in: text!, options: [], range: range) != nil
        }
    }
}
```

And I get error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[NSRegularExpression
>   enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: Range or index
>   out of bounds'

Another regex works correctly. I think that error for backslash in regex.

Comment: But how create without Detector? Only regex for dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: My NSRange code works correctly, problem in regex line

Comment: I am change utf8 to utf16 and all my validators do not working (return false, I think (project not crashing))...

Comment: If utf16 - I do not have a error. Code `v.bind(to: saveNewItemBarButtonItem.rx.isEnabled).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)` is not set enabled my Bar Button Item

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192154/discussion-between-rob-and-tkas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting the `NSRange` of a Swift `String`, you want to use `utf16` instead of `utf8`:

```
func validate() -> Observable<Bool> {
    return input.map { text in
        guard let text = text else { return false }
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count)
        return self.regex.firstMatch(in: text, range: range) != nil
    }
}
```

Personally, I find the logic between choosing `utf8` or `utf16` to be unnecessarily opaque, and I use the `NSRange(_:in:)` initializer:

```
func validate() -> Observable<Bool> {
    return input.map { text in
        guard let text = text else { return false }
        let range = NSRange(text.startRange..., in: text)
        return self.regex.firstMatch(in: text, range: range) != nil
    }
}
```

That having be said, the use of `utf8.count` when building `NSRange` would only manifest that crash if the string had non-ASCII characters in it. That might possibly explain why when you fixed this with `utf16` why the crash disappeared but that your validation is still failing. The strings must include extended Unicode characters and therefore, by definition, don’t conform to the regex.